# Issue using nested serializer with django-rest-framework

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create a nested serializer, `UserLoginSerializer` , composed of a `UserSerializer` and a `NotificationSerializer`, but I'm getting this error when it tries to serialize:

> AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for
> field `email` on serializer `UserSerializer`. The serializer field
> might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the
> `UserSerializer` instance. Original exception text was:
> 'UserSerializer' object has no attribute 'email'.

Here is my models.py:

```
class Notification(models.Model):
    kind = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    message = models.CharField(max_length=256)

class User(AbstractUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    customer_id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
```

And my serializers.py:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            "id",
            "first_name",
            "last_name",
            "email",
            "customer_id"
        ]

class NotificationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Notification
        fields = [
            "id",
            "kind",
            "message",
        ]

class UserLoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    user_info = UserSerializer(read_only=True)
    notifications = NotificationSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
```

The error occurs at the last line in this endpoint:

```
def get_login_info(self, request):
    notifications = Notification.objects.filter(recipient=request.user)
    serializer = UserLoginSerializer(
        {
            "user_info": UserSerializer(request.user),
            "notifications": NotificationSerializer(notifications, many=True),
        }
    )
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.data` attribute.

```
def get_login_info(self, request):
    notifications = Notification.objects.filter(recipient=request.user)
    serializer = UserLoginSerializer(
        {
            "user_info": UserSerializer(request.user).data,
            "notifications": NotificationSerializer(notifications, many=True).data,
        }
    )
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

You must pass the data, not the serializer objects themselves. The `data` argument allows you to pass in a dictionary of data that will be used by the inner serializers to create a serialized representation. In this case, you will pass in the serialized data from the `UserSerializer` and NotificationSerializer to the `UserLoginSerializer`, which then returns the final serialized representation of the data.

Or, you may pass user and notifications directly as such:

```
def get_login_info(self, request):
    notifications = Notification.objects.filter(recipient=request.user)
    serializer = UserLoginSerializer(
        {
            "user_info": request.user,
            "notifications": notifications
        }
    )
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Django Rest Framework model serializers have a `to_representation` method which converts the model instances to their dictionary representation, so in this case, the `UserLoginSerializer` will automatically use the `UserSerializer` and `NotificationSerializer` to serialize the user and notifications data. You can modify/change this method's behaviour by overriding it.

I hope this helps.

Comment: The second solution works. The first fails, because the nested serializers (UserSerializer and NotificationSerializer) actually have SerializerMethodFields (which I left out of the example code) and these get called with a ReturnDict() as input instead of the objects they require. So the second solution covers this case. Since I didn't mention these SerializerMethodFields, I'm giving you full credit for your answer, but I'd caution others to consider this.